# Disable Datapicker Calendar icon using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have a table which has a set of data.
Now in my table i have a checkbox for every row that enables or disables row.
When i click on checkbox that specific row should get disabled.
Issue is i am successfully able to disable the datepicker field but the calendar icon still remains enabled.

Below is the code i have been using:

For the datepicker textbox(Works Fine):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.animalBroughtDate').prop('disabled', true);
```

For the Calendar icon(Not working):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();
```

HTML:

```
<input id="animalBroughtDateId" class="animalBroughtDate dtp hasDatepicker" style="width: 100px;" type="text">

<img title="Ok" alt="Ok" src="/../..datePicker.png" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">
```

Please guide.

Comment: Can you please share your html for datepicker?

We can simply unregister the click event from the icon. But for doing so, I need to look the HTML.

Comment: Did you try to use display:none?

Comment: added the html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built in `U.I datepicker`  disable command.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.animalBroughtDate').datepicker("disable");
```

And in case you want to enable just :

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.animalBroughtDate').datepicker("enable");
```

Comment: Awesome bro! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if your found it helpful.